# Laravel delete button with HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the HTML form, not Laravel Collective.

For now I've successfully created a CRUD for a users in my CMS, but one thing bothers me:

How can I set a Delete button in my list of users, instead of the specific edit page?

Also, it will be nice when a user clicks on the Delete button to show up confirmation popup for deleting the specific user.

So, here's my code:

The controller:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->delete();

    return redirect('/admin/users'); 
}
```

The list of users page:

```
@extends('layouts.backend')

@section('content')
  <h1>Users</h1>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/admin/users/create">Create new user</a>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
        <th>Operations</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @if($users)
        @foreach($users as $user)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->role ? $user->role->name : 'User has no role'}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->status == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Not active'}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
            <td>
              <a href="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger" href="">Delete</a> // HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS?
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </tbody>
  </table>

@endsection
```

The specific edit user page:

```
@extends('layouts.backend')

@section('content')
  <h1>Edit user</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{$user->name}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{$user->email}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Role:</label>
      <select name="role_id" class="form-control">
        @if($user->role_id == 1)
          <option value="1" selected>Administrator</option>
          <option value="2">Editor</option>
        @else
          <option value="1">Administrator</option>
          <option value="2" selected>Editor</option>
        @endif
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Status:</label>
      <select name="status" class="form-control">
        @if($user->status == 1)
          <option value="1" selected>Active</option>
          <option value="0">Not active</option>
        @else
          <option value="1">Active</option>
          <option value="0" selected>Not active</option>
        @endif
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="{{$user->password}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update user" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
  </form>

  <form id="delete-form" method="POST" action="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete user">
    </div>
  </form>

  @include('inc.errors')
@endsection
```

The route:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){
     Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');

     Route::get('/admin', function(){
       return view('admin.index');
     });
    // Route::resource('admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
});
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not obvious from the code you posted, but your `DELETE` route expects `DELETE` method. As it should!

But on your list you're trying to access it with `GET` method.

Really you should just reuse the code from the edit page, which fakes `DELETE` method already.

Something like this:

```
...
<td>
    <a href="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    <form method="POST" action="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-user" value="Delete user">
        </div>
    </form>
</td>
...

...
// Mayank Pandeyz's solution for confirmation customized for this implementation
<script>
    $('.delete-user').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault() // Don't post the form, unless confirmed
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            // Post the form
            $(e.target).closest('form').submit() // Post the surrounding form
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is the best solution and simple! How did I not think about of using directly form in the loop...so, I don't need of AJAX for this. I've already tried and it's working great! 
Thank you so much, devk!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Plus one for a better solution than mine :)

Comment: hi i am also trying this kind of user delete functionality but not working   <a href="javascript:void();" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="deleteUser();" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Delete</a>

Comment: `@csrf`  and  `@method('DELETE')` curently

Comment: How we would be able to add trash icon in input field?

Comment: Great solution! Works like charm. Working on Laravel 8.10.x.

Answer (score 3):

As you have stated **it will be nice when a user clicks on the Delete button to show up confirmation popup for deleting the specific user**. For this you have to use `jquery` and `ajax`. Change the following code:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="">Delete</a>
```

to

```
<a class="btn btn-danger delete_user" href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{$user->id}}">Delete</a>
```

and put an event listener like:

```
$('.delete_user').click(function(){
  if( confirm('Are you sure?') )
  {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // Make an ajax call to delete the record and pass the id to identify the record
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've guessed I have to use AJAX for this task. OK, thank you for your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code like:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/admin/users/{{$user->id}}/delete" >Delete</a>
```

**OR** you should delete user using route name like:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.user.delete', [$user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
```

Comment: This won't work, because I don't have a route for delete method and I don't wanna create a page for that. As Mayank answered, it's best thing to use AJAX. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

option with "laravel form helper" and jquery

```
<div class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item delete-action">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </a>
    {{ Form::open(['url' => route('admin.users.destroy', $user), 'method' => 'delete']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.delete-action').click(function (e) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                $(this).siblings('form').submit();
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using route closures to delete

show.blade.php

```
 <form>
<h1>Title: {{$tutorial->title}}</h1>
<p>Title Description: {{$tutorial->title_description}}</p>
<p>Video: {{$tutorial->video}}</p>
<form action="{{ route('delete-tutorial', [$tutorial->id])}}" 
method="post">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" 
type="submit" name="Delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

for the route for deleting

```
Route::delete('tutorial/{id}',function($id){
$tutorial = Tutorial::findOrFail($id)->first();
$tutorial->delete();
return redirect('tutorial'); 
})->name('delete-tutorial');
```

Also don't forget to add this on your routes/web.php

```
use App\Models\Tutorial;
```