# Calling destroy method in resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, backend, laravel-7

I am unable to understand how to call destroy method when I use resource controller in laravel.
delete.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.destroy', '$post->id') }}"  >
@method('DELETE')
@csrf
    <select name="id">
        <option value="1">vddv</option>
        <option value="2">miss</option>
        <option value="3">miss</option>
        <option value="4">joy</option>
    </select>

      <br><br>
    <button type="submit"> Delete blog</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

resource controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\posts;
use Sessions; 


class PostController extends Controller
{ 
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');   
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $post = new posts;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('posts/read');
    }

    public function show($data)
    {
       echo "show";
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('posts.edit');
    }

    public function update(Request $req, $id)
    {
        echo posts::where('title' , $req->title)
        ->update(['body'=>$req->body]);
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = posts::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

It is calling show method as GET request is passed. please guide me how to call destroy method. As mentioned in documentation  I am passing @method('DELETE') using form method spoofing as html only recognise GET and POST method.

Comment: You cannot make delete form this way. You can only do it this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098806/laravel-delete-button-with-html-form

Comment: may be its not related, but you have a misspelled, change `{{route('posts.destroy', '$post->id') }}` to `{{route('posts.destroy', $post->id) }}`

Comment: Change `$post = Post::find($id);` instead of `$post = posts::find($id);` inside `public function destroy($id)`  and  change  `use App\Post;`  instead of `use App\posts;` in your controller

Comment: STA that's not a misspelling, that's a fundamental misunderstanding of PHP and the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code. I hope it will work.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/posts' . '/' .$post->id) }}">
  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <select name="id">
    <option value="1">vddv</option>
    <option value="2">miss</option>
    <option value="3">miss</option>
    <option value="4">joy</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" title="Delete Post">Delete</button>
</form>

// In Controller

public function destroy($id) {
  Post::destroy($id);
  return redirect('posts')->with('flash_message', 'Post deleted!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello, Brother please try this i hope it will work.
```

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE', 'url' =>route('posts.destroy', $post->id),'style' => 'display:inline']) !!}

 {!! Form::button('<i class="ft-trash"></i>delete', array('type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-defult','title' => 'Delete Post','onclick'=>'return confirm("Confirm delete?")')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```