# Route [student.delete] not defined using Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

i am a beginner of laravel. i ran into the problem with Route [student.delete] not defined. using laravel 7. when run the laravel project. what i tried so far i attached below. i attached the controller and view and route file below i don't what was a problem.

**Controller.**

```
  public function destroy(Student $student)
        {
            $student->delete();
            return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Student has been Deleteddddd');
        }
```

index.blade.php

```
       @foreach ($students as $student)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $student->id  }}</td>
    <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $student->phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ $student->address }}</td>
    <td>

        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('student.edit',$student->id) }}">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('student.delete',$student->id) }}">Delete</a>
       
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Routes**

```
 Route::get('/', 'StudentController@index');
Route::get('/students', 'StudentController@create')->name('student.create');
Route::post('/students', 'StudentController@store')->name('student.store');
Route::get('/students/{student}', 'StudentController@edit')->name('student.edit');
Route::post('/students/{student}', 'StudentController@update')->name('student.update');
//Route::delete('/students/{student}', 'StudentController@destroy')->name('student.destroy');

Route::get('/students/{student}', 'StudentController@destroy')->name('student.destroy');
```

[image]

Comment: please take a look this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#available-router-methods

Comment: i saw i but couln't solved

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098806/laravel-delete-button-with-html-form/46099194 or do some research on it